# Complex logarithm, my answer is wrong

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am trying to calculate $$\log(-1+i)$$

I have $$\log(-1+i) = \ln|(-1+i)| + i\operatorname{Arg}(-1+i)$$

$$ = \ln\sqrt2 + i3\pi/4$$

However when I checked that in matlab and wolfram alpha they have

$$\frac{\ln\sqrt2}{2} + i3\pi/4$$

Can't see what Im doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28-1%2bi%29) returns $\dfrac {\ln 2}2+i\dfrac{3\pi}4$ so that both are equal!

Comment: God damn, I am terrible for overlooking numbers and signs. Its gonna cost me in the exam :(

Comment: @jim: fast reading is a common and shared default ;-)